# How to make it so it accepts only ints when the message is not int?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code I wrote:

```
if  msg.startswith ("!gamble"):
    
    await message.channel.send(f"""{message.author.name} how much would you like to gamble (Max 10)""")
elif  not  (message.content) in commands and int(message.content) in (idpoints) :
        await message.channel.send(f"""{message.author.name} gambled {int(idpoints[int(message.content)])} and {gamblestate}!""")
elif  not  (message.content) in commands and (idpoints[int(message.content) > 10]) : #> int(message.content) 
    await message.channel.send(f"""{message.author.name} can't gamble {message.content} cause he is too poor """)
elif not (message.content) in commands and (idpoints[int(message.content) > 10]): 
    return None
```

I would like to return a message like "Answer has to be A full number !" whenever someone writes a word instead of a number.

Comment: Note: discord.py is not a good starting point for people "new to python", as it uses advanced features such as decorators and async/await

Comment: First of all, I would recommend using [`discord.py` commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) to accomplish this, as you will be able to take arguments when the members use the command(s). You would then be able to *not* depend on splitting strings and instead depend on arguments passed. I agree with @SuperStormer, that you probably shouldn't start out with `discord.py` when learning Python.

Comment: I now but without a project to follow I don't believe I'll have the motivation to learn python... 
I am doing since I wish to learn .Net forms applications next year at school and python was my best option to learn meanwhile... I tried doing it using .Net but the discord.net library was way more complicated then i thought.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/kindling.html is a great list of projects for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

If you strong type the command args, you can handle the exception later and display the error message to the users.

```py
@bot.command()
async def your_command(ctx, foo: str, bar: int):
    # do stuff with your code
    pass
```

When the user does
`!your_command spam egg`, discord will throw `BadArgument` error since it was expecting an `int` but got a `str`.

You can then handle the error with:

```py
@your_command.error
async def your_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Answer has to be an integer!")
```

Please do read [discord.py documents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) even though it may seem very intimidating. It is super well documented.

Comment: ty very much ! ill will try it ! 
ps.. ive already tried reading the discord.py docs, even watched videos about them but because of the nature of english not being my mother language and me not taking my adhd pills it always ends up the same.. ty for the advice tho !